# Adding float-left class (Bootstrap 4) to div negates <a><img></a> link

Tags: html, css, image, layout, bootstrap-4

Weird situation... this code results in a picture and the related text BELOW it.  Importantly, the picture is properly clickable, the text wrapping is not what I want (see below):

```
            <div class="col-md text-center " style="margin-top:15px;">
                <h3>Heading</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md" style="margin-top:15px;">

                <div class="col-xs-5 nopad">
                    <a href="{link to external website}"><img src="images/picture.jpg"  style="max-height: 145px; margin-right: 15px; margin-bottom: 5px; "></a>

                </div>

                <div class="col nopad" style="width:100%;">
                    Lorem impsum, etc..........
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

My goal is to have the text wrap to the right and bottom of the photo and still have the img clickable.  When I add "float-left" to the  before the  tag, the image is no longer clickable.  This is the code that doesn't work:

```
            <div class="col-md" style="margin-top:15px;">

                //LINE BELOW CONTAINS FLOAT-LEFT
                <div class="col-xs-5 nopad float-left">
                    <a href="{link to external website}"><img src="images/picture.jpg"  style="max-height: 145px; margin-right: 15px; margin-bottom: 5px; "></a>

                </div>

                <div class="col nopad" style="width:100%;">
                    Lorem impsum, etc..........
                </div>

            </div>
```

I have searched with no luck.  I have rearranged code and no luck.  The presence or absence of the float-left seems to clearly be the source of the problem.

Comment: It would be valuable if the person providing the down vote could provide a reason.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it good you want to have clickable image on the left and text wrapped around it on right and bottom. Here is what works for me

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="floated">
      <a href="#"> <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"> </a>
  </div>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
</div>
```

```css
#container{
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}
#floated{
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    background: red;
}

#floated img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I have put `px` on elements width but it will work with `%` too..

Hope it helps

Happy Coding

Comment: Thank you. It's not a Bootstrap 4 solution, but it works perfectly fine when contained in the row.  I guess it was the use of columns within columns that wasn't playing nicely with float-left. 

If you don't mind, could you upvote the question.   I don't know where or why there was a downvote.   Thank you!

Comment: I am glad I helped :)